# Burninate the [data-science] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There are a small number (339) of posts tagged as [data-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-science).

I'm a Data Scientist myself, but I think this tag is probably worthless. Almost all 150,000 R questions, all MATLAB, Octave, and probably 50% of Python and Excel questions would qualify as being data science.

- It's used so rarely and so inconsistently I don't think it provides any value as a filter.
- It may lead to OP's tagging a question in what they think is an appropriate way, while really missing the tags that would get their question read by the appropriate communities.
- If a question is about data science in a sense that's abstracted from any particular language or code, then it's a Cross Validated or Data Science SE question more than a Stack Overflow question.

What do you think?

Comment: The ones related to data science are generally off topic, yes, but they are almost never closed.

Comment: @ayhan once you remove the tag, it may become more visible to others.

Comment: Besides, Data Science… it's like Botany (not real science). :)

Comment: @R.Richards On behalf of botanists everywhere I'm offended ;)

Comment: I don't get the joke, @R.Richards. What do you mean that botany is "not a real science"? Do you not think that plants exist?

Comment: It's from the movie, The Martian. It was a joke in the movie. And no, plants do not exist! :)

Comment: Cats exist. Therefore, [cat-herding](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=herding%20cats) must be a science?

Comment: That's one of the biggest smallest number.

Comment: @ManojKumar Most of the tags that would be used instead of data-science have hundreds of thousands of questions in them

Comment: @jpaugh Considering I used to be a cat herder for a living, I'd say, yes.

Comment: @jpaugh no, the analogy is "cats exist, therefore felinology exists"

Comment: @TylerH Agreed; I just meant that *the subject exists* is not a sufficient criterion for an endeavor to be a science. Side note: Ever notice that any field which has science in the name isn't a science?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I agree; though data science was originally synonymous with computer science, the subject of data science itself (like computer science) is an incredibly broad one: "extracting knowledge or insights from data" per the tag's own description. Like the subject of computer science, I think real questions on data science (rather than just questions where the tag is thrown on) are likely too high level, broad, or possibly opinion-based for this site.

I would say burninate. Glancing at the first page of questions tagged with it, its existence doesn't seem to improve the value or searchability of any of the ones I looked at.

Comment: OP said in 2016: *"a small number (339)"* it's up to 9,089 in early 2024... They should have burninated it when they had the chance.

Comment: @bad_coder Holy...