# Is it appropriate to tag a question about Gaussian Processes as a "data-science" question?

Tags: discussion, support

My question, [How to incorporate individual measurement uncertainties into Gaussian Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74151442/how-to-incorporate-individual-measurement-uncertainties-into-gaussian-process), was editted by the community to omit the [data-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-science) tag I included. This surprised me.

I noticed this question [Getting "TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'" for linear regression in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74166291/getting-typeerror-fit-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y-for-linea), which discusses regression, has been tagged as [data-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-science).

The definition of the data-science tag is:

> Implementation questions about data science. Data science concerns extracting knowledge or insights from data, in whatever shape or form. It can contain predictive analytics and usually takes a lot of data wrangling. General questions about data science should be posted to their respective communities. `

Is my question too general a question about data science? It seems like it is about predictive analytics, particularly about how to incorporate uncertainty data with measurement data.

I don't understand why the data-science tag was removed. Would it be OK for me to add it back?

Comment: why not just ask the person who removed it via a comment on the question? You'll have to @ their name.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the advise. I just did this. The text editor didn't prompt me to enter the name like it did here, which confused me. I hope it worked.

Comment: It wouldn't have, @kilojoules , as you have since editted the post. You can only ping them if they were the last person to edit the post

Comment: @Larnu Actually, any of the editors can be pinged [ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020). They don't have to be the last editor on the post. In all cases, editors usernames won't auto-complete. So long as you spell the username correctly, the user should be notified.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, the [data-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-science) tag is what's known as a "meta tag." There aren't any concrete definitions, but [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) from the early days of SO should give you the idea. My personal definition is that the presence of the tag doesn't give any information as to what the question is about, and the way in which the question could be answered isn't changed by the presence of that tag.

There have been [previous questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338759/burninate-the-data-science-tag) about the validity of this specific tag. While it hasn't been officially blacklisted, I would guess it was edited out of your question to discourage its use based on the editor's personal views about it. You can of course revert the edit to your question, it's unlikely anyone's going to get into an edit war over it. But keep in mind the purpose of question tags and how it would (or wouldn't) help other users answer your question.

---

Also of note, there is a [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) where you may be more likely to find subject matter experts on this sort of thing.